# Shifting polygons in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

If I compile the following code I get no error:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
\draw plot [mark=*, samples at=    {22.5,67.5,112.5,157.5,202.5,247.5,292.5,337.5,22.5}] (\x:1);
\draw[shift={(0 cm, 2*sin(67.5) cm)}] plot [mark=*, samples at={22.5,67.5,112.5,157.5,202.5,247.5,292.5,337.5,22.5}] (\x:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Notice that I translate the second octagon using the vector (0,2*sin(67.5)) and the compiler seems to interpreter correctly the second component.
On the other side, when I try to compile the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
\draw plot [mark=*, samples at={22.5,67.5,112.5,157.5,202.5,247.5,292.5,337.5,22.5}] (\x:1);
\draw[shift={(2*cos(67.5) cm, 0 cm)}] plot [mark=*, samples at={22.5,67.5,112.5,157.5,202.5,247.5,292.5,337.5,22.5}] (\x:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get an error message:

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named 2*cos(67 is known.
See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.11 \draw[shift={(2*cos(67.5) cm, 0 cm)}]
plot [mark=*, samples at={22.5,67...
```

It seems that it doesn't recognize the vector (2*cos(67.5), 0), in particular the 2*cos(67.5) component... Can someone tell me why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you have `()` in a component of a coordinate, you need to put braces around the component, otherwise the parser will see the closing `)` as the closing `)` of the coordinate. That is, you need `({<x expression with parens>}, {<y expression with parens>})`

In addition, it seems it doesn't work to put the `cm` right after `cos(67.5)`, but you can put it after the `2` instead.

[image: code output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
\draw plot [mark=*, samples at={22.5,67.5,112.5,157.5,202.5,247.5,292.5,337.5,22.5}] (\x:1);
\draw[shift={({2cm*cos(67.5)}, 0cm)}] plot [mark=*, samples at={22.5,67.5,112.5,157.5,202.5,247.5,292.5,337.5,22.5}] (\x:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I put some labels on the edges of the octagons? Can I color some of the edges using the same `\draw plot` command?

Comment: @EM90 To color individual edges, you need multiple `\draw` statements I believe. You could use polar coordinates for labels as well, e.g. `\node at (35:1.1) {a};`, or you do something like `\path (22.5:1) -- node[auto] {b} (67.5:1);`. (By the way, when asking follow up questions about something that is unrelated to your original question, consider posting a new question instead of using comments like this.)