# Problem with plotting coordinates in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, errors, coordinates

I have a problem trying to add a point using [`pgfplots`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots). I want to plot a complex number, `4^(1/3)*(cos(2pi/9) + i*sin(2pi/9)).` This gives that the x-component should be `cos(2pi/9)*4^(1/3)`, and the y-component should be `sin(2pi/9)*4^(1/3)`. However, when using the code here, I get the error message

> Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, I could not read the plot coordinates near '*4^(1/3)'. Please check for format mistakes.

The strange thing is, it is only when `4^(1/3)` is multiplied with `sin`, in the y-part, that I get this error. So

```
\addplot[black, mark = *] coordinates{( cos(2*pi/9)*4^(1/3), (sin(2*pi/9)} {};
```

works, and the x-component is correctly plotted. I have tried adding a `)` after the sin-argument, but that does not change the problem. Is it a parentheses problem? If so, is there another way to take the cubic root of a number that doesn't involve `4^(1/3)`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
ytick ={-7,...,8}, yticklabels={$-7i$, $-6i$, $-5i$, $-4i$, $-3i$, $-2i$, $-i$, $0$, $i$, $2i$, $3i$, $+3i$, $+4i$, $+5i$, $+6i$, $+7i$, $+8i$},
axis lines = center,
grid=both,
minor tick num=1,
ticks=both,
xlabel=$Re(z)$,
ylabel=$Im(z)$,
ymin=-2,
ymax=+2,
xmin=-4,
xmax=+4
]

\addplot[black, mark = *] coordinates{( cos(2*pi/9)*4^(1/3), 
(sin(2*pi/9)*4^(1/3)} {};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. This is essentially the same problem as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393936/shifting-polygons-in-tikz/393938#393938, so you need `\addplot[black, mark = *] coordinates{({cos(2*pi/9)*4^(1/3)},{(sin(2*pi/9)*4^(1/3)})};`  (the final `{}` is not needed).

Comment: Also note that the default angular unit of `pgfplots` is degrees, not radians, so you might want to replace `2*pi` by `360`, otherwise your plot will probably not look the way you want.